# Problem in loading bootstrap js in magento sub website

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I have `Magento ver. 1.9.2.1`, I have setup two sub website with two sub domain.

Everything working there but on both sub website `bootstrap-datepicker.js`, `bootstrap-timepicker.js`, `bootstrap-datepicker.js` has path of sub domain like :
`http://sub.main.com/skin/frontend/package/theme/js/`.

But it should be `http://main.com/skin/frontend/package/theme/js/`.
While all other css and js have main domain path in sub website.

How to solve that?

Answer (score 2):

@Vinaya You should edit skin urls for sub websites, it should be http://main.com/skin/ instead of {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/

Go to System-> configuration -> Web and edit Base Skin URL in Unsecure and Secure tab. Please change scope while changing URLs

Comment: I did that for skin, media and js url.

Comment: Did you cleared the cache and checked it agian?

Comment: Yes, I did. but not working after that.